# Unable to access WebCenter Sites with fwadmin user

Tags: oracle, authentication, oracle11g, webcenter, webcenter-sites

Error:

> This account is not authorized to access this site. To gain access to
>   the system, you will need to login with an account authorized to
>   access this site. For additional questions, please contact your system
>   administrator.

Oracle says "The user does not have any roles on the site".
Link:
https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=469675110594161&id=1991585.1&displayIndex=2&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=tecmcxrrr_423#SYMPTOM

fwadmin was the only user which I had to access. Since I had shared my creds, someone might had changed roles.

When I checked userpublication table as mentioned in the link, it looks fine. Help me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link, GeneralAdmin ACL for fwadmin was missing in the DB. Inserted a new row and restarted the managed server. Solved.

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=469675110594161&id=1991585.1&displayIndex=2&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=tecmcxrrr_423#SYMPTOM